# Why does this strncpy() implementation crashes on second run?

Tags: c, strncpy

Why does this strncpy() implementation crashes on second run, while the first run works ok?

> ### strncpy
>
> Copy characters from string Copies the first `n` characters of source
>   to destination. If the end of the source C string (which is signaled
>   by a null-character) is found before `n` characters have been copied,
>   destination is padded with zeros until a total of `n` characters have
>   been written to it.
>
> No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if
>   source is longer than `n` (thus, in this case, destination may not be
>   a null terminated C string).

```
char *strncpy(char *src, char *destStr, int n)
{
    char *save = destStr; //backing up the pointer to the first destStr char
    char *strToCopy = src; //keeps [src] unmodified

    while (n > 0)
    {
        //if [n] > [strToCopy] length (reaches [strToCopy] end),
        //adds n null-teminations to [destStr]
        if (strToCopy = '\0') 
            for (; n > 0 ; ++destStr)
                *destStr = '\0';

        *destStr = *strToCopy;
        strToCopy++;
        destStr++;
        n--;

        //stops copying when reaches [dest] end (overflow protection)
        if (*destStr == '\0')
            n = 0; //exits loop
    }

    return save;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    char st1[] = "ABC";
    char *st2;
    char *st3 = "ZZZZZ";
    st2 = (char *)malloc(5 * sizeof(char));


    printf("Should be: ZZZZZ\n");
    st3 = strncpy(st1, st3, 0);
    printf("%s\n", st3);

    printf("Should be: ABZZZZZ\n");
    st3 = strncpy(st1, st3, 2);
    printf("%s\n", st3);

    printf("Should be: ABCZZZZZ\n");
    st3 = strncpy(st1, st3, 3);
    printf("%s\n", st3);

    printf("Should be: ABC\n");
    st3 = strncpy(st1, st3, 4);
    printf("%s\n", st3);

    printf("Should be: AB\n");
    st2 = strncpy(st1, st2, 2);
    printf("%s\n", st2);

    printf("Should be: AB\n");
    st2 = strncpy(st1, st2, 4);
    printf("%s\n", st2);
}
```

Comment: Does this even compile? `strnacpy` is undefined.

Comment: Please don't put the question in the title only, put it in the body of the actual question together with some descriptive text.

Comment: Because you run out of allocated memory. First try is to reserve more space for `st2` string

Comment: Every time I post a question I hope I didn't make a stupid mistake. I totally meant `if (strToCopy == '\0')` (I did leave a comment though)

Comment: `if (strToCopy == '\0')` is still wrong - you probably meant `if (*strToCopy == '\0')` ?

Comment: @GeorgeGaál `strncpy()`'s "feature" of tail-filling the target buffer with 0's out to 'n' on an under-copy is probably second only to the failure to place a 0 on exact-copy or over-copy in terms of "didn't know it did that" factor. It still amazes me how many people *use* that function without knowing *either* of those features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get a segmentation fault because

```
char *st3 = "ZZZZZ";
```

the destination is a string literal. String literals must not be modified, and often they are stored in write-protected memory. So when you call

```
strncpy(st1, st3, n);
```

with an `n > 0`, you are trying to modify the string literal and that results in a crash (not necessarily, but usually).

In the copy loop, you have forgotten to dereference `strToCopy`

```
if (strToCopy = '\0')
```

and wrote `=` instead of `==`, so `strToCopy` is set to `NULL`, causing further dereferences of `strToCopy` to invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: ...and string literals are `const` when written in this way.

Comment: Agree. Because original string isn't modified, the real function prototype must be `char *strncpy(const char *src, char *destStr, int n)`

Comment: @ThiefMaster: They're not `const` (in C, but are in C++), although modifying them is UB.

Comment: Then how does it modify it on the first run? what should I do in order to be able to modify the string? Thank you for the help.

Comment: @tempy: You need to allocate it, either as an array (on the stack) or using `malloc` (on the heap).

Comment: @tempy On the first run, you pass a length of 0, so the loop isn't run at all, and nothing bad is attempted.

Comment: @netcoder I get an error that `char st3[] = "ZZZZZ";` is unmodifiable.

Comment: @tempy For what exact code? `char st3[] = "ZZZZZ";` declares and initialises an array of six `char`s (five 'Z' plus the 0-terminator) that may be modified. If your compiler objects to that, it violates the language standard.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want this:

```
if (strToCopy = '\0')
```

Instead, what you probably meant to do is this:

```
if (*strToCopy == '\0')
```

In general, using [yoda conditions](http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html) will save you much headache from comparison-vs-assignment conflation issues:

```
if ('\0' == *strToCopy)
```

Comment: Better than using nasty syntax, always compile with warnings enabled, e.g. `gcc -Wall ...` - this will catch dumb mistakes like `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: @PaulR Do you find Yoda Conditions to be nasty syntax? (If so, how come?) The problem with using `gcc -Wall` is that some legacy C code is written with legitimate assignment operations in the test conditions

Comment: Yes, the Yoda syntax hack is confusing for beginners, less readable/natural and these days unnecessary. For legacy code that generates warnings then these warnings can be be preferably fixed or at least disabled on a per-file basis as necessary.

Comment: @PaulR `-Wall -Werror` if thats the case. Shoot the messenger =P

Answer (score 0):

```
while (n > 0)
    {
        //if [n] > [strToCopy] length (and reaches [strToCopy] end),
        //adds n null-teminations to [destStr]

        *destStr = *strToCopy;
        //stops copying when reaches [dest] end (overflow protection)
        if (*destStr == '\0')
            break; //exits loop
        strToCopy++;
        destStr++;
        n--;


    }
if (*destStr != '\0') *destStr = '\0';
```

In the main:

```
printf("Should be: ZZZZZ\n");
    st3 = strncpy(st1, st3, 0);
    printf("%s\n", st3);
```

this wrong because the length you want to copy is `0` so you will not obtain `ZZZZZ`